# Android external data storage problems

Tags: android

I'm trying to store data on the SD card, according to the guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) I should be using `getExternalFilesDir()` (API level 8), I would really like to do so but calling
`File directory = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);` keeps returning `null`, I'm using my main activity as context.
Then I tried reverting to use `File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`, it correctly returns the SD root, but apparently I am unable to create the suggested "/Android/data/package_name/files/" directory:

```
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(root, GlobalConstants.EXTERNAL_SAVE_DIR);
    boolean canCreate = dir.mkdirs();
```

In this code `canCreate` is false (EXTERNAL_SAVE_DIR is obviously /Android/data/package_name/files/).

Is there anything I'm missing, maybe should I ask permissions on the Manifest (I found nothing about)? I've read `getExternalFilesDir()` has a bug where contents get deleted on application update, I don't really care about that and I would rather use it instead of the other one as I'm trying to conform to API 8 and I like the idea of it handling the directory name for me.

Any idea?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add the following to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Otherwise you are not allowed to write to the SD card. If you are using Eclipse, you can use the permissions tab of the manifest editor do add it.

Comment: Damn, I don't know how I missed it, and I checked!

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that the files aren't created automatically when writing but one has to use `file.createNewFile()`

Comment: I don't understand why the documentation doesn't mention this permission in Data Storage section. +1 it solved my problem.

Comment: Dear reader - if you have the same problem with premissions in Manifest, try to reboot phone or enable then disable USB storage. I had situation on 2.2, where external storage was mounted and permission was in place, but app was unable to write anything. Connecting to computer and switching on->off USB storage mode fixed this issue for me.